# git add --patch stopped prompting for my user

Tags: git

I'm having issues with git add -p.

Up until about a month ago it worked fine, now it skips the prompts (it doesn't even show them). When changing to a different user on the same worktree, it works fine. Comparing environment variables looks OK.

`git --version: 2.14.2.666.gea220ee40`

I am at a loss as what else to compare.

Comment: Compare `git config --list` of the two users.

Comment: Thanks, this brought me to rename my `~/.gitconfig` file, after which by process of elimination, I discovered the issue was caused by `color.ui = always`

Comment: Which shell do you use? Did you change your shell lately?

Comment: No. I think it's an issue with git. It started after I updated git. I submitted a bug report to the git mailing list.

Comment: This makes sense, as `git add -p` is a Perl program that attempts to break up the unified diff format, and the color-setting strings could confuse it about where the diff hunk boundaries are. You might as well answer your own question here at this point.

Answer (score 4):

So after reporting this on the git mailing list, it seems this is a known behavior due to the following commit: https://github.com/git/git/commit/136c8c8b8fa39f1315713248473dececf20f8fe7

If I get the gist of the description, it seems that `color.ui = always` is something that's moving away.

More information can be also found on the git mailing list:

https://public-inbox.org/git/86D0A377-8AFD-460D-A90E-6327C6934DFC@gmail.com/T/#u

Comment: I had this same issue & could not for the life of me figure out what happened. Thank you!